# How to obtain file name from a SHA1 ID string with JGit?

Tags: jgit

If I am given the SHA1 ID of a particular file as a string, how can I obtain its name in JGit?

Comment: An object id (SHA-1) in Git points either to a blob, a commit or a tree. Please tell us where exactly the SHA-1 you are holding points to. In doubt use `git show <object-id>` to test.

Comment: Thanks for reply. All objects id point to a blob.

Comment: If you need to know the file(s) that point to the given blolb-id, you could reverse-find them by scanning all or some relevant tree objects to reveal the file names. But note that the same blob may be referenced by multiple files (i.e. there are file with different names that have the exact same content). Let me know if you need further directions.